# pandas SparseDataFrame insertion

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

i would like to create a pandas SparseDataFrame with the Dimonson 250.000 x 250.000. In the end my aim is to come up with a big adjacency matrix.

So far that is no problem to create that data frame:

```
df = SparseDataFrame(columns=arange(250000), index=arange(250000))
```

But when i try to update the DataFrame, i become massive memory/runtime problems:

```
index = 1000
col = 2000
value = 1
df.set_value(index, col, value)
```

I checked the source:

```
def set_value(self, index, col, value):
    """
    Put single value at passed column and index

    Parameters
    ----------
    index : row label
    col : column label
    value : scalar value

    Notes
    -----
    This method *always* returns a new object. It is currently not
    particularly efficient (and potentially very expensive) but is provided
    for API compatibility with DataFrame
...
```

The latter sentence describes the problem in this case using pandas? I really would like to keep on using pandas in this case, but its totally impossible in this case!

Does someone have an idea, how to solve this problem more efficiently?
My next idea is to work with something like nested lists/dicts or so...

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Do it this way

```
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(columns=np.arange(250000), index=np.arange(250000))

s = df[2000].to_dense()
s[1000] = 1
df[2000] = s

In [11]: df.ix[1000,2000]
Out[11]: 1.0
```

So the procedure is to swap out the entire series at a time. The SDF will convert the passed in series to a SparseSeries. (you can do it yourself to see what they look like with `s.to_sparse()`. The SparseDataFrame is basically a dict of these SparseSeries, which themselves are immutable. Sparseness will have some changes in 0.12 to better support these types of operations (e.g. setting will work efficiently).